# How to test for a message and an error message simultaneously in R testthat?

Tags: r, testthat

I'm looking to unit test a function that produces a connection. It outputs a message that contains the connection details during execution.

I want to test the following:

1. The message appears as expected (`expect_message(fn(),"blah")`)
2. There is no error (`expect_error(fn(),NA)`)
3. Object created is a specific class (`expect_is(fn(),"PostgreSQLConnection")`)

I could do `res<-fn()` and then do the `expect_is()` from it, but **how can I perform tests on both the message and the (lack of an) error whilst calling the function.**

Ideally, I'd like to evaluate all three simultaneously and in such a way I could then safely close the connection afterwards.

```
library(testthat)
fn<-function(){
  message("blah")
  obj<-"blah"
  class(obj)<-c("PostgreSQLConnection",class(obj))
  return(obj)
}

expect_message(fn(),"blah")
expect_error(fn(),NA)
expect_is(fn(),"PostgreSQLConnection")
```

PS The `expect_message` and `expect_error` functions use functions like `throws_error` which may or may not be deprecated- the docs are a little confusing on that point. `?throws_error`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `testthat::evaluate_promise` you can get the various aspects of a function call, store the results, and then test for the items you need to test.

In this case the code becomes:

```
library(testthat)

fn<-function(){
  message("blah")
  obj<-"blah"
  class(obj)<-c("PostgreSQLConnection",class(obj))
  return(obj)
}

res<-evaluate_promise(fn())

expect_equal(res$messages,"blah")
expect_equal(res$warnings,character())
expect_s3_class(res$result,"PostgreSQLConnection")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also chain `expect_message` and `expect_error`:

```
fn1 <- function(){
  message("blah")
  obj<-"blah"
  stop("someError")
}
expect_error(expect_message(fn1()), "someError")
# or
expect_message(expect_error(fn1(), "someError"))
```